# eye texture issue

Tags: texturing, node-editor, normals

i'm not sure why the eye texture is appearing this way. I've already tried recaculating normals / flipping them for the eye but this has not worked. any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That last image shows your up is not aligned to make use of the image detail, did you unwrap it again after already having it work?